# Inserir elemento numa árvore binária de procura

Tags: c, árvore-binária

Estou a ter dificuldades ao adicionar um elemento numa árvore binária de procura . A função retorna 1 se o elemento a inserir ja estiver na árvore e 0 caso contrário. O retorno da função funciona bem mas **ao imprimir a árvore o novo elemento não aparece na nova árvore**.
Aqui está o meu código :

```
int adiciona (Abin a, int x)
{

  int n;

  if (a == NULL)
  {
    Abin novi = (Abin)malloc (sizeof (struct sbin));
    novi->valor = x;
    novi->esq = NULL;
    novi->dir = NULL;
    n = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    if (x == a->valor)
    { n = 1; }
    if (x > a->valor)
    { n = adiciona (a->dir , x); }
    if (x < a->valor)
    { n = adiciona (a->esq , x); }

  }

   return n;
}
```

Será que o erro está no meu código ? Se estiver , qual a maneira certa de resolver esta função ?

Answer (score 2):

Em nenhum ponto nesse código você adiciona os novos ramos criados aos ramos superiores da árvore.
Isso é - você chama a função `adiciona` recursivamente corretamente, a função  `adiciona` cria uma nova árvore de um único nível e insere o valor, mas não insere essa nova árvore nos níveis do pai.

Como em C é complicado uma funçao retornar mais de um valor (no caso o seu "n" e o novo ramo da árvore) - o melhor é criar o novo ramo, quando for necessário sem chamar a função adiciona com um "NULL" como raiz - (por que aí ela tem onde adicionar o ramo criado).

Então talvez uma das formas mais simples seja reorganizar sua função mais ou menos assim

```
Abin cria(void)
{
  return (Abin)malloc (sizeof (struct sbin));
}

int adiciona (Abin a, int x)
{
  int n;

  if (x == a->valor)
    { n = 1; }
  if (x > a->valor)
    { 
      if (!a->dir)
      { 
        a->dir = cria();
        a -> dir -> valor = valor;   
        n = 0;
      }
      else
      { n = adiciona(a->dir, x); }
    }
  if (x < a->valor)
    { 
      if (!a->esq)
      { a -> esq = cria();
        a -> esq -> valor = valor;
        n = 0;
      }
      else
      { n = adiciona (a->esq , x); }
    }
  return n;
}
```

(excepcionalmente eu mantive seu padrão de identação - mas ele não é nenhuma das formas preferidas para linguagens com chaves)

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer `a` apontar para o seu elemento `novi`. Ele não imprime nada porque você aloca um valor na memória mas não adiciona ele a sua árvore.

Comment: Do jeito que o código está, mudar o valor da variável `a` não resolve - (no entanto usar uma referência de referência resolveria e itnterferiria menos com design original do que a minha sugestão)